# Post request payload in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to write a python script to get the tracking info from this page: https://www.purolator.com/en/app-tracker.page. 
Using F12 in Chrome, I got the header and the request payload, no form data just request payload. The tracking number I'm trying is: GRH000241377

Here's my code:

```
 header = {
        'authority': 'api.purolator.com',
        'method': 'POST',
        'path': '/tracker/puro/json/shipment/search',
        'scheme': 'https',
        'accept': 'application/vnd.puro.shipment.trackingevent+json',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-CA',
        'content-length': '90',
        'content-type': 'application/vnd.puro.shipment.trackingevent+json',
        'origin': 'https://www.purolator.com',
        'referer': 'https://www.purolator.com/en/app-tracker.page?pin=GRH000241377&sdate=2019-12-09',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'
    }

    data = {
        'pins':'[{"pin":"GRH000241377","sequenceID":1}]',
        'searchOptions':'{"includeReference":true}'
    }


    url = "https://www.purolator.com/en/app-tracker.page"
    response = requests.post(url, headers=header, json=data)
    res_json = response.json()
```

Response code is 200 but when i print the response.text i get the same page without any result, and if try to get `response.json()` i got next error, I'm assuming that error is because i have no json in the response

```
'Error occurred : \n Error Message: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'
```

Presumably error is on data or header construction but can't figure out the problem.
Any idea?
Thanks

Here are the response headers:

```
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.purolator.com
content-length: 1102
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' *.hs-cpggpc.ca *.canadapost.ca *.cpggpc.ca *.purolator.com *.epost.ca
content-type: application/vnd.puro.shipment+json
date: Tue, 14 Jan 2020 00:37:38 GMT
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=86400; preload
svn-build-number: Purolator.buildLevel.20190622.BF_2019A-B15568.15568
via: 1.1 199fd61d7551d8868317c5b53cc7d24d.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-apigw-id: GQ8E3HOV4osFhyQ=
x-amz-cf-id: Yqyt1uuT9NuucZiYP7arFLAFnTdKbK8yAfRrJ5nfnV7kUyNbhXH0OQ==
x-amz-cf-pop: IAD89-C3
x-amzn-remapped-connection: keep-alive
x-amzn-remapped-content-length: 1102
x-amzn-remapped-date: Tue, 14 Jan 2020 00:37:38 GMT
x-amzn-requestid: a04f8174-fc03-49f5-864c-23bb76ff4434
x-backside-transport: OK OK,OK OK,OK OK,OK OK
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: ALLOW-FROM https://https://www.purolator.com
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: Could you please attach the response header as well?

Comment: A POST request doesn't have to return anything, that's what GET is for

Comment: What's in `response.content` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps.

Python code:

```
import requests

header = {
  'authority': 'api.purolator.com',
  'method': 'POST',
  'path': '/tracker/puro/json/shipment/search',
  'scheme': 'https',
  'accept': 'application/vnd.puro.shipment.trackingevent+json',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-CA',
  'content-length': '90',
  'content-type': 'application/vnd.puro.shipment.trackingevent+json',
  'origin': 'https://www.purolator.com',
  'referer': 'https://www.purolator.com/en/app-tracker.page?pin=GRH000241377&sdate=2019-12-09',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'
}

data = {"trackingNumbers":[{"trackingNumber":"GRH000241377", "type":"Unspecified","sequenceID":1}]}

url = "https://api.purolator.com/tracker/puro/json/shipment/trackingEvent/summary/search"
response = requests.post(url, headers=header, json=data)
res_json = response.json()

print (res_json)
```

Output:

```
{"trackingResults": [{"searchStatus": "Found", "foundBy": "Pin", "searchCriteria": {"trackingNumber": "GRH000241377", "type": "Unspecified", "sequenceID": 1}, ..., "isStateBehind": False}
```

Comment: please expound and explain what the problem is and how you solve it. Don't expect people to do a diff on the code

Comment: This URL "https://www.purolator.com/en/app-tracker.page" provides shipment tracking. I enter this URL in Google Chrome and hit enter, then click Develop Tools and go to Network tab for tracing network request sources. I type PIN into the input field, and click "Track Now" button. In Network tab, I can see all network activity in the Network Log, then I found this URL "https://api.purolator.com/tracker/puro/json/shipment/trackingEvent/summary/search", which returns tracking information.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works, but i need a little bit more info than is not shown in the response, im trying to use this payload:`data = {"pins":[{"pin":"GRH000241377", "sequenceID":1}], "searchOptions":{"includeReference":True}}` but the response is: `[{'code': 'E019', 'description': "[JSV0001] Invalid value type 'array'."}]`

Comment: Thanks Neda Peyrone finally solved, problem was on url and headers!